# Java - How do I add a new value to an existing key in a Hash Map. 1 key, multiple values

Tags: java, methods, maps

I am trying to create a method that, when given a key and a value, can access the map via the key and then either add or replace that specific value.
My Hash Map is created like so:

```
public Band(){
    musicians = new HashMap<>();
}
```

And I can add new entries like so, with band acting as the key:

```
public void addMapEntry(String band, String name, String instrument, int experience){
    musicians.put(band, new Musician(name, instrument, experience));
}
```

My new method header look like this:

```
public void addValue(){ }
```

I have tried using the put method but I can't get it work as I'd like.
I have also tried iterating through the map, but I've only ever used that method to return map objects in a list, whereas I don't want to return anything in this method. I want to be able to send it two arguments (the key and the value) and have it only replace that specific value.

I hope I have been clear in my explanation.

Comment: You need another collection, probably a list as a value for your hashmap

Comment: I don't find it very clear. What have you tried? and what didn't you like about it.

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't shown the declaration of `musicians`...

Comment: "I can't get it [to] work as I'd like" - so what would you like, what does it do instead, and what else have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Java Map is single value for each key.

If you need multiple values for a single key, you should make the type a collection of the appropriate type and add your own logic for adding a new value.  Your `Band` class should have methods to add/remove a `Musician` and handle the details in the private implementation.

```
public class Band {

   private Map<String, List<Musician>> members = new HashMap<String, List<Musician>>();

   public void addMusician(String key, Musician musician) {
       if (this.members.containsKey(key) {
           List<Musician> musicians = this.members.get(key);
           if (musician != null) {
               musicians.add(musician);
               this.members.put(key, musicians);
           }
       }
   }

   public void removeMusician(String key, Musician musician) {
       // should be clear enough from the add method.
   }
}
```

Comment: This is great and actually makes sense to me. I'm trying to test it by passing some data into the argument but I'm not sure how to enter a Musician object as an argument. I'm doing it like this: aBand.addMusician("Black Sabbath", Tony Iommi);

Comment: N o, call new to create an instance and pass it into the method.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most suitable for you is to use Guava Multimap

```
 ListMultimap<String, String> musicianMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Then add as many musicians to your band

```
musicianMap.put("Beatles", new Musician("Jhon Lennon"));
musicianMap.put("Beatles", new Musician("Paul McCartney"));
musicianMap.put("Beatles", new Musician("Ringo Starr"));
musicianMap.put("Beatles", new Musician("George Harrison"));
```

And you can pull them all using just key.

```
musicianMap.get("Beatles")
```

This will return a list of `["John Lenon", "Paul McCartney", "Ringo Starr"]` of course these will objects of class Musician.

Comment: This is certainly correct, except for the misspelling of John Lennon's last name and the exclusion of George Harrison.  Guava is a fine library, but it comes with the cost of an additional dependency.  It's possible to solve this problem easily without it.

Comment: Corrected name of beatles band members as suggestion by @duffymo, and I agree that Guava will be an additional dependency, but I think its methods save a lot of boiler-code work.

Comment: Not a lot - two methods, as I showed.  Thank you for the correction.  In no way do I intend this as a criticism of your answer.  The dependency choice is one we all have to make.  https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/

Comment: Yeah, but you skipped the logic and code you need to write putting an element in the list, first we have to check if there is a list already exists or not, if not create one, then insert into it. same goes while pulling this out of map, we are always afraid of those NullPointerException.

Comment: You picking at small things now.  I didn't realize the size spoon required to feed you.  I'll add it.

Comment: And I agree we should choose our dependencies wisely, but Guava is a well tested library from Google, and weighs only a few KBs.

Comment: Ok I agree these might be small things from your perspective or even mine, but look at question... this guy doesn't knows much about Map, and your code will teach him List first in order to use Map :D :D

Comment: I think @DaveRanjan is right, utilities are made for a reason. One should start using these as early as possible.